# How do I disable automated SQL Server Backups?

Tags: backup, sql-server

SQL Server seems to be doing full backups (.bak) at random intervals then storing them into, 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup

Is there an option to automatically backup databases in SQL Server 2012? I've checked the database properties already for an option to do so. If not, my guess would be another service on my machine is automating these backups.

Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)

Comment: I haven't used SQL Server 2012 yet but there's nothing in previous versions of SQL Server that performs automatic database backups. Have you checked for any Maintenance Plans or SQL Server Agent jobs that may be performing the backups?

Comment: What version of SQL Server is doing the automated backups, since you're asking about 2012?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatated backup system in SQL Server, either it is a [agent task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) that is running them or some kind program connecting to the server and running the backup command. Both are "user generated" and not automatic by the system.

You will need to track down which software is performing the backups and stop that software, you can check the [Agents in Sql Server Managment Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUNGu.jpg), but if it is not there then it is one of the softwares you run on your computer (or computer network if the server is exposed to the network) that is generating the backups.

Running the query

```
select * from msdb.dbo.backupset
```

will show you the [backupset](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186299.aspx) table which has all the backups that have been created recently, through that you may be able to start to track back to what is running those backups.